# How to enforce the "reset" of a component matched several times by a route definition?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I am writing an application modelled as below:

[image]

The intention is to have `/` redirected to `/<uuid>`. `/<uuid>` itself is managed by the component `User` and `User` passes `uuid` to `Case` as a prop.

Within `Case` there is a button to reset the URI path to `/`, triggering the mechanism above again.

---

```
// content of routes.ts

import { RouteRecordRaw, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { uid } from 'quasar'

const route = useRoute()

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: () => {
      return {path: `/${uid()}`}
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/:uuid',
    component: () => {console.log('matched /uuid'); return import('pages/User.vue')}
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Within `User.vue` there is

```
<Case :uuid="route.params.uuid"></Case>
```

where

```
const route = useRoute()
```

---

**My problem:** when pressing the button that resets the path to `/`, I see the path changing, but the message `matched /uuid` is not displayed again in the console (it is displayed once, at the reload of the page).

It seems that the [documentation for Lazy Loading](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) suggests that the component is initialized only once (and I am not sure what it means in terms of routing a new path to it):

> The component (and components) option accepts a function that returns a Promise of a component and Vue Router will only fetch it **when entering the page for the first time**, then use the cached version.

I would like the component to "know" that it has been "called" on each reset of the path to `/` (redirected to `/:uuid`), so that it can react to the change of `uuid` and push it to the `Case` component. **How to do that?**

Comment: [Reacting to Params Changes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: @MichalLevý: thanks, this is the workaround I finally implemented in the meantime (and now I know that's the right thing to do). Thanks.

Comment: To really force a proper reload, you should manipulate the `window.location` object. Is this what you are looking for?